# Gregorian to Hebrew

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gregorian-calendar

How to convert a gregorian date into the equivalent hebrew date?
Also please tell about these calendars as I am not having much knowledge of these.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a handy class called [`NSCalendar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html).  You create one like this:

```
NSCalendar * gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSCalendar * hebrew = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSHebrewCalendar];
```

Once you've got the calendar objects, you can use them to convert a date around to various representations:

```
NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents * components = [gregorian components:NSUIntegerMax fromDate:date];
NSDate * hebrewDate = [hebrew dateFromComponents:components];

NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
NSLog(@"hebrew: %@", hebrewDate);
```

On my machine, this logs:

```
date: 2011-01-09 23:20:39 -0800
hebrew: 1751-09-25 23:20:39 -0800
```

If you want to convert stuff to a more readable format, you use [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[formatter setCalendar:gregorian]; //this is usually unnecessary; it's here for clarity

NSLog(@"date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);

[formatter setCalendar:hebrew];

NSLog(@"hebrew: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:hebrewDate]);
[formatter release];
```

This logs:

```
date: January 9, 2011
hebrew: Tishri 9, 2011
```

It would appear that `NSDateFormatter` is using the gregorian date, but at least it's got the right month name, right?

**edit**

Actually, I goofed.  If you just set the calendar of the `NSDateFormatter`, you don't have to worry about converting the date at all.  See:

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[formatter setCalendar:hebrew];

NSLog(@"hebrew: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
[formatter release];
```

This logs:

```
hebrew: Shevat 4, 5771
```

Much better!  Isn't Cocoa awesome?

Comment: Tishrei is the first month of the civil year (as opposed to the ecclesiastical year), so it looks like it just interpreted 2011-01-09 as a Hebrew date. Probably not a good idea to go with the first example of extracting date components. The second example is correct, the 9th of January 2011 is the 4th of Sh'vat, 5771.

Comment: @dreamlax agreed. extracting date components is something you'd only do if you needed to do some relative calculations.