# Hebrew/Jewish Calendar in Android

Tags: java, android, calendar

I need to display a Jewish calendar in my app, there is only a Gregorian calendar view on the API.
In each box of the calendar (each day) I need to display the appropriate date in Hebrew letters.
Maybe I should create a Gregorian calendar view, and convert it to a Jewish calendar, something like this:
[Gregorian to Hebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644451/gregorian-to-hebrew)

Comment: A new alternative is shown in [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47511177/2491410) which is also available in Time4A using the dependency `dependencies {
    compile group: 'net.time4j', name: 'time4j-android', version: '3.37-2017c'
}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have Zmanim Project

http://www.kosherjava.com/zmanim-project/

And here it is an example of use.

http://www.kosherjava.com/tag/jewish-calendar/